# What does TotalOperatingTime mean in AppleSmartBattery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Recently I updated my MBP's battery and use a command: `ioreg -rn AppleSmartBattery | grep -i capacity` to check it.
And it shows

```
"AppleRawCurrentCapacity" = 4359
      "AppleRawMaxCapacity" = 6700
      "MaxCapacity" = 6700
      "CurrentCapacity" = 4359
      "LegacyBatteryInfo" = {"Amperage"=18446744073709550957,"Flags"=4,"Capacit"=6700,"Current"=4359,"Voltage"=11610,"Cycle Count"=2}
      "BatteryData" = {"LifetimeData"={"TotalOperatingTime"=28160,"UpdateTime"=1674981257,"AverageTemperature"=273,"Raw"=<0000000000483ff4000108f100000000060ae9c40080e467b24000000000000001d9004e1106084b33091fc6155be5271a8ce074eadce8ac01110006e0070031>,"TimeAtHighSoc"=<00000000230500001200000000000000>},"Serial"="C01514309YEF90MA4","ChemID"=2955,"Flags"=192,"DataFlashWriteCount"=0,"PassedCharge"=18446744073709550538,"Voltage"=11637,"ResScale"=167,"RaTableRaw"=(<0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000>,<0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000>,<0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000>),"StateOfCharge"=65,"Qmax"=(6580,6600,6590),"CycleCount"=2,"DesignCapacity"=6600,"SystemPower"=957,"AdapterPower"=0,"PMUConfigured"=1856,"DOD0"=(9280,9344,9248),"PresentDOD"=(40,41,40),"CellVoltage"=(3869,3875,3866)}
      "DesignCapacity" = 6600
```

Seemed other fields are reasonable, but a little wired for **"TotalOperatingTime"=28160**
because it should be a small number?
Does any one know why?

Comment: Why should it be a small number? If you find out what that number represents then you will get the information you are looking for, but you need to find out how "operating time" is represented and how you convert it to hours or weeks or whatever units are used.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanna know how it is represented. in my opinion, it maybe be like "Total used time" so I feel wired